# I cannot boot into Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, but when I reboot the computer I cannot switch between the two systems. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which OS is booting for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your grub is not listing both Ubuntu and Windows try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If you are unable to access Grub I would take a look at [this question about restoring grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Try to update grub menu. Boot into Ubuntu and open terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) enter the command

> sudo update-grub

Restart to see if worked or not.

If that did not work then use `Boot-Repair`